# From list create parent child model list

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

when i am trying to fetch a list from a table, i want to make it model list like parent child.the model and sample code what i have tried it doesn't give desire result.

```
public class EPItemZonePriceGetDto
{
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }
    public List<EPZonePriceDto> ItemZonePrices { get; set; }

}
public class EPZonePriceDto
{
    public int ZoneId { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
}
```

the selection from table data list contains like sample data fetched given below:

```
ZoneId  ItemCode    Price
1   000100  10
1   000633  10.5
2   000100  11
2   000633  8.8
3   000100  9
3   000633  9.5
4   000100  8.5
4   000633  9.5
IEnumerable<EPItemZonePriceGetDto> data = _entities.ItemZonePrices.Where(x 
=>x.ItemCode == itemcode).ToList().Select(s=> new EPItemZonePriceGetDto
        {
            ItemCode = s.ItemCode,
            ItemZonePrices = new List<EPZonePriceDto>()
            {
                new EPZonePriceDto()
                {
                    Price = s.Price.ToString(),
                    ZoneId = s.ZoneId
                }
            }
        }
```

i expected the out put like below

```
 { itemZonePrices :
     {
    itemCode:017273
    zonePrice:
    [
      { zoneId:1, price:”1.23” },
      { zoneId:2, price:”1.23” }

    ]
   }}
```

but it gives me

```
{itemZonePrices :
   {
    itemCode:017273
    zonePrice:
    [
      { zoneId:1, price:”1.23” }

    ]
   },
   itemZonePrices :
   {
    itemCode:017273
    zonePrice:
    [

      { zoneId:2, price:”1.23” }
    ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to group the data on `ItemCode` and then project data as required.

Try something like following :

```
var data = _entities.ItemZonePrices
                  .Where(x => x.ItemCode == itemcode).ToList()
                 .GroupBy(x => x.ItemCode)
                 .Select(s=> new EPItemZonePriceGetDto
                            {
                                ItemCode = s.Key,
                                ItemZonePrices = s.Select( x => 
                                                      new EPZonePriceDto()
                                                         {
                                                           Price = x.Price.ToString(),
                                                           ZoneId = x.ZoneId
                                                         })
                            });
```

Comment: sorry ehsan may b i didn't check my model what i have given. it wont be like what u given coz itemzonprices is a list of array. thanx for ur reply though i have solved it man